# How can I implement an NRV in brickwork or masonry?

Tags: drainage, sewer

Location: Nagpur, India

Glossary:
NRV = Non-return valve / One-way valve
PVC = Poly Vinyl Chloride
SWR = Soil, Waste, Rain

Over the years repair/renovation of the street in front of the house has resulted in the grade reversing; the street is now actually running several inches higher than the premises. We are one of the two original structures left dating back to the 1920s.

The main sewage tank into which we drain receives our wastewater almost at the bottom of the chamber. An overflow pipe was fit downstream into the channel which is just so that any sludge flows - anything that flows not settles to the bottom of that chamber. The main chamber itself always runs higher atleast a foot higher than our outlet pipe since the overflow pipe downstream was commissioned.

I can't expect to convince the civic body of my impending trouble in time for next monsoon. Further, since my lines date back to the 20s - ripping them out at an exit depth of about 8' is going to be a pain financially, and in terms of effort involved. The old pipes are clay - so a PVC/SWR NRV can't be married to it.

How can I implement an NRV in brickwork?

Comment: NRV = non-return valve?  Also, where are you on the planet?

Comment: Yeah, spelling out what all the acronyms are would be helpful so that Everyone, no matter where they are on the planet knows what you're talking about. Even if they don't know right away, they can search for the words, not just 3 letters which could have dozens of definitions in different industries.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Updated.